# Access repeater delegate items by model property

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I am trying to draw a graph structure in Qt using QML. I want to draw lines representing edges between vertices. The vertices are created in a repeater with a given vertexID, x, and y. The edges have two vertexIDs that should be connected.

The vertices can be dragged/moved and the endpoints of the edges should follow. Since the edges depend on the vertices, I am loading them after the vertices are completed.

However, I am not sure how to access the vertex delegates by their vertex ID and bind their positions to the edges. How can I accomplish this? Is there any way of doing it without looping through every repeater item? Is there a better approach in general to this kind of dependency in QML?

Here is sample code of what I am trying to achieve:

```
import QtQuick 6

Rectangle {
    id: window
    width: 800
    height: 600
    color: "black"

    Repeater {
        id: vertices
        function getVert(vID) {
            // How to return vertex with given vID and bind it to edge?
        }
        model: ListModel {
            ListElement {
                vID: 3; x: 100; y: 200
            }
            ListElement {
                vID: 4; x: 600; y: 500
            }
            ListElement {
                vID: 7; x: 500; y: 300
            }
            ListElement {
                vID: 9; x: 400; y: 200
            }
        }
        delegate: Rectangle {
            id: vertex
            x: model.x
            y: model.y
            width: 10
            height: 10
            radius: 5
            color: "white"

            function centerPos() {
                return Qt.point(x + width / 2.0, y + height / 2.0)
            }

            Drag.active: vertexMouse.drag.active
            MouseArea {
                id: vertexMouse
                anchors.fill: parent
                drag.target: vertex
            }
        }
    }

    Repeater {
        id: edges
        model: ListModel {
            ListElement {
                vID1: 3
                vID2: 7
            }
            ListElement {
                vID1: 3
                vID2: 4
            }
        }
        delegate: Item {
            Loader {
                id: edgeLoader
            }
            Component {
                id: edge
                Canvas {
                    x: 0
                    y: 0
                    width: window.width
                    height: window.height

                    property var pos1: vertices.getVert(vID1).centerPos()
                    onPos1Changed: requestPaint()

                    property var pos2: vertices.getVert(vID2).centerPos()
                    onPos2Changed: requestPaint()

                    onPaint: {
                        var ctx = getContext("2d")
                        ctx.clearRect(x, y, width, height)

                        ctx.lineWidth = 4.0
                        ctx.strokeStyle = "white"

                        ctx.beginPath()
                        ctx.moveTo(pos1.x, pos1.y)
                        ctx.lineTo(pos2.x, pos2.y)
                        ctx.stroke()
                    }
                }
            }

            Connections {
                target: vertices
                Component.onCompleted: {
                    edgeLoader.sourceComponent = edge
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you use a dictionary for vertices, like `{3: Qt.point(100, 200), 4: Qt.point(600, 500), ... }`?

Comment: The vertex/edge models comes from C++. The vertices/edges/QML/C++ need to all be kept in sync.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[REWRITE]

No need for `Canvas`, you can use `Shape`, `ShapePath`, and `Line`.

We create a lookup table to help look up `vID` in the `ListModel`.

The (x, y) coordinates from the `verts` `ListModel` are used to draw both the vertices and edges so that any changes that happen to the `verts` `ListModel` will automatically update both vertices and edges.

I made use of `DragHandler` to reduce the code needed for UI action.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Shapes
Page {
    ListModel {
        id: verts
        ListElement { vID: 3; x: 100; y: 200 }
        ListElement { vID: 4; x: 600; y: 500 }
        ListElement { vID: 7; x: 500; y: 300 }
        ListElement { vID: 9; x: 400; y: 200 }
    }
    ListModel {
        id: edges
        ListElement { vID1: 3; vID2: 7 }
        ListElement { vID1: 3; vID2: 4 }
    }
    property var lookup: {
        let _lookup = [ ];
        for (let i = 0; i < verts.count; i++)
          _lookup[verts.get(i).vID] = i;
        return _lookup;
    }
    Repeater {
        model: verts
        Rectangle {
            x: model.x - 5
            y: model.y - 5
            width: 10
            height: 10
            color: tapHandler.pressed  && "orange"
                || dragHandler.active && "green"
                || "red"
            TapHandler { id: tapHandler }
            DragHandler { id: dragHandler }
            onXChanged: model.x = x + 5
            onYChanged: model.y = y + 5
        }
    }
    Repeater {
        model: edges
        Item {
            property var s: verts.get(lookup[vID1])
            property var e: verts.get(lookup[vID2])
            Shape {
                ShapePath {
                    strokeColor: "blue"
                    startX: s.x; startY: s.y
                    PathLine { x: e.x; y: e.y }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

Comment: Thank you for the PathLine tip.

The first example would probably not work for me. In my case, the vertex IDs can be spread out a lot (imagine if vertices can be deleted and the id is not reused).

In the second example, how do you render the vertices? I had one repeater for edges and another for the vertices. The vertex position is slightly modified by QML so I wanted to access the vertex directly from the edge repeater to get the vertex position without losing the separation between model/view. Is there a way to do that in your second example?

Comment: 2nd repeater would work. However, I just updated the first repeater to paint the vertices whilst doing the edges. I may need to revisit this problem because you really need a fast way to lookup vID without doing repeated scans as well as be able to paint all the vertices right? To do both would require further thought to come up with something doesn't do excessive looping.

Comment: Yes, I want to avoid iterating through every vertex to find the desired vID. The single repeater edit now draws vertices that are connected to edges but not the vertices with no edge. It also draws vertices multiple times if it is connected to multiple edges. In addition, if I add a MouseArea to a vert and drag it then the edge does not follow.

Comment: Hi, I rewrote the answer. Changes made are: (1) create a lookup array maps vID to ListModel index - this array eliminates the need to reiterate, (2) implement DragHandler on vertices (I think this is better than MouseArea), (3) and restored ListModel so that vertex changes result in edge changes.

Comment: Thank you! This is a great solution. I appreciate all the other suggestions as well.